# Is it possible to create an UI with a table View with two columns?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, uikit, multiple-columns

I‘m an absolute beginner! I want to program an app in iOS. The UI of the main screen should have two columns. The left column should have a static width. The right column should be much wider than all iOS displays. When I swipe over the left column up or down the content of the right column should follow this reaction. The same reaction should be the other way around. When I swipe over the right display left or right, the content should move left or right and should be pulled out of the screen on the right or left side. Is it possible to realize this with two table view or two scroll views?[image]

Comment: you can use just one ScrollView, and set it's size larger than UIScreen

Comment: @arash But how can I fix the content of the left column in one ScrollView. I want to push the content of the right column unter the left column. It should react like an Excel spreadsheet with a fixed first column and a fixed fort row.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can achieve this, the best one would be with a `UICollectionView`, you can even use a `UICollectionView` within a `UITableView`'s cell.

I think you are looking for something like **kishikawakatsumi's** [SpreadsheetView](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/SpreadsheetView), if you are a beginner, give it a shot.